# Training MXNet with large batch size and small number of GPUs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu, mxnet

When training MXNet, if the batch size is large(say 128), and the number of GPUs is small(say 2), and each GPU can only handle a few samples each iteration(say 16). By default, the maximum batch size of this configuration is 16 * 2 = 32.

In theory, we can run 4 iterations before updating the weights, to make effective batch size 128. Is this possible with MXNet?

Answer (score 1):

Editing this answer with a more streamlined approach (memory-wise). You have to configure each parameter to accumulate gradients, run your 4 forward passes, run backwards, and then manually zero your gradients.

As per https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/aggregate-gradients-manually-over-n-batches/504/2

"This is very straightforward to do with Gluon. You need to set the grad_req in your network Parameter instances to 'add' and manually set the gradient to zero using zero_grad() after each Trainer.step() (see [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/gluon.html#mxnet.gluon.Parameter.grad_req)). To set grad_req to 'add':

```
for p in net.collect_params().values():
    p.grad_req = 'add'
```

"And similarly call zero_grad() on each parameter after calling Trainer.step(). Remember to modify batch_size argument of trainer.step() accordingly."

Vishaal